# Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript' when using FBSDKApplicationDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have updated swift 3 and I found many errors. This is one of them :

> Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'

For the following line

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
        FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, sourceApplication: options["UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey"] as? String, annotation: options["UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsAnnotationKey"] as? String)

        return true
    }
```

I am not sure why I am getting this, does anyone else know ?

It works well in previous version 7.3.1 swift 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of the `options` dictionary has changed from `[String: AnyObject]` to `[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any]` this means you should subscript with `UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey` instead of a `String` like you're doing now.

Try this:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    guard let sourceApplication = options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String,
        let annotation = options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation] else {
            return false
    }

    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url,
                                                                 sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
                                                                 annotation: annotation)

}
```

This code extracts the keys you're looking for from the `options` and passes them to the `FBSDKApplicationDelegate`. Note the usage of `UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication` and `UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation` to access values in the options dictionary.

Comment: Your code is only available in version iOs 9.0 above. What if i still use version 8.4. Thanks

Comment: According to Apple's documentation this version of the method is iOS9+ only. I'm not sure what the best course of action is to support both iOS8 and iOS9 because this method simply doesn't seem to be compatible with both.. https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623112-application

Comment: Yes, maybe I need to follow apple rules. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is how deal with with versions before and after iOS 9 with swift 3 and Xcode 8

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: Any) -> Bool {


    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}

@available(iOS 9.0, *)
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {


    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(app, open: url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as! String, annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])

}
```

Hope it helps!